# How to set datatime column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some datatime columns on my dataframe. One of them appear with the object type and the other appear as datatype. How to pass tho object type one as datatype also ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bitT9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftEww.png)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_ = pd.to_datetime(DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_)`?

Comment: It gives me this error message:
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1013-08-20 00:00:00

Comment: And `DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_ = DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_.astype('datetime64')`?

Comment: It gives me the same error message than before.

Comment: Last chance :) `DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_ = pd.DatetimeIndex(DL_2.DATE_ENTREE.to_numpy())`

Comment: What does it mean `"1013-08-20 00:00:00"`??? Typo?

Comment: Same error. It's ```datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 14, 0, 0)```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

According your comments, it seems you have some bad dates.

Use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'`

```
DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_ = pd.to_datetime(DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_, errors='coerce')
```

To find bad dates:

```
DL_2.loc[pd.to_datetime(DL_2.DATE_ENTREE_, errors='coerce').isna(), 'DATE_ENTREE_']
```